# Which Fourier series are "legal"?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

Let's consider a continuous function $f(x)$ and real numbers $\lambda_n=(\alpha+\beta n)\pi$ where both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are integers.  In any interval $I$, is it true that 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n\sin(\lambda_n x)
\quad\text{and}\quad
a_n=\frac{\int_I f(x)\sin (\lambda_n x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{\int_I \sin^2(\lambda_n x)\,\mathrm{d}x}?
$$

If not, can I modify the hypothesis so that it becomes true?

Comment: you missed to write question :-)

Comment: Definitely not true in general. To begin with, even the ordinary Fourier sine series may not be pointwise convergent everywhere if you only assume $f$ continuous. Secondly, for your formula for $a_n$ you need the functions $\sin(\lambda_n x)$ to be orthogonal w.r.t. the $L^2$ inner product on $I$, which puts restrictions on the length of the interval.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks for your comment. I am not a mathematician and so I dont know too much about this. The theorem that I was looking for is that from  Sturm-Liouville.